# Android BottomNavigationView with custom views as icons

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying out the new BottomNavigationView from the Android Support library. For one of the menu items I would like to have a custom view so that I can add a circular user image programatically as an icon.

After using, this does not seem possible with either this support component or the roughhike/BottomBar library. Any ideas? The question could be simplified on how to use a layout in a menu as an icon and if this is possible with BottomNavigationView or other libraries.

Comment: Looking for same thing. The support library's BottomNavigationView is so horribly lame. I'm trying to control 'count badges' that may or may not be shown next to the menu items, and thus am looking for the ability to control the views..

Comment: That's exactly what I need as well. So far it seems like we need to wait for BottomNavigationView to get better, unless you don't need to customize anything. I'm looking into all the libraries mentioned in this [article](https://blog.autsoft.hu/now-you-can-use-the-bottom-navigation-view-in-the-design-support-library/), if non of them work I'll try to make my own with TabLayout (maybe?).

Comment: I found a third party Bottom Navigation View-type library that does everything we want - including having built-in 'notification badge count' functionality. [https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) It's a shame the official control is so useless, but I'm using this for now and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'll take a look into this one. I want to compare it to https://github.com/Ashok-Varma/BottomNavigation since it seems to do everything we want as well.

Comment: Oh interesting, I looked at that one too but totally missed the fact that it had badges as well! Well haven't encountered any bugs yet with the one I mentioned earlier, connected it with a Fragment-based `ViewPager` and everything working just fine w/ badges. :)

Comment: This library is great so far. I'll make it the accepted answer until the Support one gets better. There are several good libraries that can do this bottom navigation and each may suit different scenarios better. If this library is not good for you consider:

Comment: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar ^

Comment: @apSTRK Did you come across any way to have custom layout for MenuItem in latest version of Bottom Navigation. I tried with all attributes it supports, like action views, but could not make it.

Comment: @cgr I haven't tried the latest version of Bottom Navigation so I wouldn't know the answer to your question. Look at their material design documentation, they usually follow it to the letter so it may still not be too customizable.

Comment: materialTheme is the way to go. Included in the  
   bottomNav.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.action_more).number = 2