# How to create the custom item of Bottomnavigationview Android?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, bottomnavigationview

I am using the `Bottomnavigationview` for tab-bar in my application, for it, i am using the following code.Please check it once.

**Layout :-**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"     
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

And I get the following **Result** from it, please check the image for it.

[image: Current Result]

***But the problem is that***, I need the custom item of the `Bottomnavigationview`, like in below image there is **red** `TextView` count which is on the home item of the `Bottomnavigationview`, Please check the below image.

[image: Expected Result]

I have searched for it and get the ***third party library*** for it, which is able to create the view which I want.Please check the library of it [Click here](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) .***Is it not possible to NOT use any third party library and use the only `Bottomnavigationview` for it?***

I have searched here on **SO** but did not get the expected result, please check the below link which I have visited.

[1. First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515456/custom-item-in-the-bottomnavigationview)
[2. Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653955/bottom-navigation-view-with-custom-item-actionlayout)
[3. Third Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902557/android-bottomnavigationview-with-custom-views-as-icons)
[4. Forth Link](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation)
[5. Fifth Link](http://en.proft.me/2017/01/30/android-bottomnavigationview-tutorial-example/)

Please help me to short out from this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: No need to go with bottomsheet, create your own custom image and textview

Comment: @MohitSuthar ..I think `It is not a good practice ` which u are saying.I have functionality of the tab,so i am using the tab.Creating the view and inflate that view on each and every screen is more tedious work bro..Any way thanks for input..Please suggest me another way

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have done the above task as the following approach, please have a look on the solution

> **Layout**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/header_color"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />  /// YOUR MENU ITEMS FOR THE BOTTOM NAVIGATION
```

Your badge count layout be like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationsBadge"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And than after your badge drawable be like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp" />
</shape>
```

And at the last, you need we need to inflate our badge layout into our **MainActivity.java** , where we use the BottomNavigationView, please check the following code for it.

```
    BottomNavigationMenuView mbottomNavigationMenuView =
            (BottomNavigationMenuView) mBinding.bottomNavigation.getChildAt(0);

    View view = mbottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(4);

    BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) view;

    View cart_badge = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.profile_view,
                    mbottomNavigationMenuView, false);

    //// AND THAN SET THE COUNTER BADGE, AS FOLLOW
    ((TextView) cart_badge.findViewById(R.id.notificationsBadge)).setText("5");

    itemView.addView(cart_badge);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using androidX , please refer below code :

```
  BottomNavigationView mbottomNavigationView =findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        BottomNavigationMenuView mbottomNavigationMenuView =
                (BottomNavigationMenuView) mbottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);

        View view = mbottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(1);

        BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) view;

        View cart_badge = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.notification_badge,
                        mbottomNavigationMenuView, false);

        itemView.addView(cart_badge);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used tab layout with a custom view in it

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainTabBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

```
    var mainPagerAdapter = MainPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager!!)
        viewPager.setAdapter(mainPagerAdapter)
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mainPagerAdapter.getCount())
        for (i in 0 until mainPagerAdapter.getCount()) {
            val tab = mainTabBar.newTab()
            val tabView = mainPagerAdapter.getTabView(i, this)
            tab.setCustomView(tabView)
            mainTabBar.addTab(tab)
        }
        val tab = mainTabBar.getTabAt(0)
        if (tab != null) {
            tab.select()
            val view = tab.customView
            mainPagerAdapter.changeColorOfTabView(view!!, true, this,tab.position)
        }
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)

        mainTabBar.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                viewPager.currentItem = tab.getPosition()
                val view = tab.getCustomView()
                mainPagerAdapter.changeColorOfTabView(view!!, true, this@MainActivity, tab.position)
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                val view = tab.getCustomView()
                mainPagerAdapter.changeColorOfTabView(view!!, false, this@MainActivity, tab.position)
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        })
```

```
    fun getTabView(i: Int, context: Context): View {
//        val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Vazir-FD.ttf")
        val tabView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_main, null) as LinearLayout

        val text = tabView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tabTextView)
        val icon = tabView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.drawableTop)
        text.setText(getPageTitle(i))
        text.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
//        text.setTypeface(typeface)
        icon.setImageResource(getIconResId(i))

        if (i == 3) {
            tabView.isSelected = true
        }
        return tabView
    }
```

tab_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawableTop"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawableTop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/toggle_text_color_gray_red"
        android:textSize="11sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This supports tablet but does not fill all the space